# A world twisted?

Tags: lateral-thinking

My friend told me that he went to a strange place:

> "It looks like a jail, but there are no wardens.  There are only
>   silences behind the bars.  However", my friend said, "we could feel it
>   from their eyes, as if they are reaching out for help."
>
> "More importantly, they are not the murderers.  The murderers are set
>   free!  Bloods have been found all over their body.  No one cares about
>   it, nor is anyone surprised by the unusual circumstance."
>
> "One by one, the innocents behind the bars are sent to their death
>   sentence, by the murderers!"
>
> "Aren't you gonna call the police?"  I asked.
>
> "It's no use", my friend answered.  "In fact, there are far more 
>   people involved in this murdering than you could have imagined."

Where did my friend go?  A world twisted?

Comment: I think I accidentally created a question with at least 2 answers, Codenewbie's answer is my intended answer but Aggie's answer fits perfectly as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your friend went to

> The slaughterhouse.
> The innocents are the livestock that are butchered to obtain meat and hide, and the murderers are the butchers at the slaughterhouse. The butchers usually have their clothes covered in blood from the slaughter of the animals, which is quite a common sight in such places. Animal slaughter is not a crime, so the police will not get involved, and the people involved in the "murder" are several starting from the ones who rear the animals right until the consumers of the meat.

Comment: the 'jail' would have 'wardens' though.

Comment: @Spacemonkey: Hmm, good eye. But barring that one line, every other clue fits in its native form without the need for much interpretation.

Comment: I was thinking of this one too. Good show.

Comment: I might have thought this too, except it said "there are only silences behind the bars." I suppose that could mean animals don't talk...but animals make **some** kind of noise, so it can't be "only silences".

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps your friend went to a:

> Music score.

Silences behind the bars:

> Rests, or silences could be said to be hiden behind the staff.

The murderers are set free:

> The notes played aloud kill the silence, and are set free by the instruments that play them.

Bloods have been found all over their body.

> Music notes sometimes could look like drops of black blood.

One by one, the innocents behind the bars are sent to their death sentence, by the murderers!

> Silence is always killed by noise, and each rest is killed by a note.

...there are far more people involved in this murdering than you could have imagine.

> There are very many musical performers. Vocal artists, instrumentalists, percussionists, etc.

Comment: Did you mean store?

Comment: @warspyking: A music score is the result of writing down music.

Comment: I figured it was looking for an actual place though.

Comment: This is the answer I had thought of, too. Connection also with video killed the radio star.